# How can I make my iOS app crash when a view is laid out ambiguously?

Tags: ios, crash, autolayout

I want to notify developers on my team, and prevent them from going further, when they have created a view that has ambiguous constraints. To do this, I want to make the phone crash (in debug). I could poll periodically to see if any views in the hierarchy have `hasAmbiguousLayout` set to true, but this is not great. However, it looks like iOS reports ambiguous layouts in its Runtime Issues area. So, there must be some equivalent of `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` for ambiguous layouts. How can I make it crash?

Comment: Perhaps I could use method swizzling or dyld interposing to hook into something, but the question is what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swizzle `UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews` and `UIView.layoutSubviews` and assert `!hasAmbiguousLayout == false`

Here is a playground example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

extension UIViewController {
  @objc private func swizzledViewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    assert(!view.hasAmbiguousLayout)
    print("inside the swizzledViewDidLayoutSubviews method for \(Self.self) ")
    swizzledViewDidLayoutSubviews()
  }

  private static let swizzleImplementation: Void = {
    guard let original = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews as (UIViewController) -> () -> Void)),
      let swizzled = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(UIViewController.swizzledViewDidLayoutSubviews)) else {
        return
    }
    method_exchangeImplementations(swizzled, original)
  }()

  static func swizzle() {
    _ = swizzleImplementation
  }
}

class V: UIViewController {}
UIViewController.swizzle()
let v = V()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = v
```